# Excel POI celda en negrita

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Buenas que tal Saben cual es el método para poner el texto de una celda en negro aplicar el estilo desde java con la clase poi Gracias y un saludo.

```
HSSFWorkbook a = archivoexcel();
    HSSFSheet hoja = a.createSheet("LOGS");
    int longitud = datos.size();
    Iterator ithora = hora.iterator();
    Iterator itnom= nom.iterator();
    Iterator itmin = min.iterator();
    Iterator itentorn = entorno.iterator();
    Iterator it = datos.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {

            HSSFRow filacabe = hoja.createRow(0);
            HSSFCell celdaca = filacabe.createCell((short) 0);
            HSSFCell celda2ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 1);
            HSSFCell celda4ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 2);
            HSSFCell celda5ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 3);
            HSSFCell celda6ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 4);
            HSSFCell celda7ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 4);
            celdaca.setCellValue("Nombre test");
            celda2ca.setCellValue("MENSAJE");
            celda4ca.setCellValue("Entorno");
            celda5ca.setCellValue("Hora");
            celda6ca.setCellValue("FECHA");
            celda7ca.setCellValue("Nombre");




            HSSFRow fila = hoja.createRow(i + 1);
            HSSFCell celda = fila.createCell((short) 0);
            HSSFCell celda2 = fila.createCell((short) 1);
            HSSFCell celda4 = fila.createCell((short) 2);
            HSSFCell celda5 = fila.createCell((short) 3);
            HSSFCell celda6 = fila.createCell((short) 4);
            HSSFCell celda7 = fila.createCell((short) 4);
            String info = it.next().toString();
            String[] infoslip = info.split(";");

            celda.setCellValue(infoslip[0]);
            if (infoslip[1].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                celda2.setCellValue(infoslip[1]);
                celda4.setCellValue(itentorn.next().toString());
                celda5.setCellValue(ithora.next().toString()+": "+itmin.next().toString());
                celda6.setCellValue(fecha);
                celda7.setCellValue(itnom.next().toString());
            } else {
                celda2.setCellValue(infoslip[1]);
                celda4.setCellValue(itentorn.next().toString());
                celda5.setCellValue(ithora.next().toString()+": "+itmin.next().toString());
                celda6.setCellValue(fecha);
                celda7.setCellValue(itnom.next().toString());

            }

        }
    }
    this.archivo(a);
```

este es mi código y quería poner en las cabeceras el formato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te comparto un método que generé en el cual puedes definir varias propiedades para una celda.

```
/**
 * @param: book:
 *             libro de trabajo de excel
 * @param: letterSize:
 *             Tamaño de letra
 * @param: color:
 *             valor del nuevo color
 * @param: isBold:
 *             define si el texto será en negritas
 * @param: border:
 *             define si la celda tendrá borde
 * @param: backGround:
 *             define si la celda tedrá fondo
 * @param: horizontalAlign:
 *             tipo de justificado horizontal
 * @param: verticalAlign:
 *             tipo de justificado vertical
 */
protected CellStyle setCellStyle(Workbook book, short fontsize, Short color, boolean isBold, boolean border,
        boolean backGround, HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlign, VerticalAlignment verticalAlign) {

    CellStyle cellStyle = book.createCellStyle();
    Font headersFont = book.createFont();

    headersFont.setFontHeightInPoints(fontsize);
    headersFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    headersFont.setBold((isBold));
    cellStyle.setFont(headersFont);
    if (horizontalAlign != null) {
        cellStyle.setAlignment(horizontalAlign);
    }
    if (verticalAlign != null) {
        cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlign);
    }
    cellStyle = (backGround) ? setCellBackground(cellStyle, color) : cellStyle;
    cellStyle = (border) ? setCellBoder(cellStyle) : cellStyle;

    return cellStyle;
}
```

y la forma de utilizarlo es la siguiente:

```
CellStyle titleStyle = setCellStyle(book, (short) 14, IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex(), true, false, false,
            HorizontalAlignment.LEFT, null);
```

saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que crear un estilo:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = book.createCellStyle();
Font cellFont = book.createFont();
cellFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
cellStyle.setFont(cellFont);
```

Y luego aplicarlo a celda que lo requiera:

```
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```